# NetBeans PHP built-in web server - rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, netbeans, url-rewriting, webserver

I am working in NetBeans IDE 7.2 on Windows 7.

I need to set some rewrite rules for my web project.

Can I use custom `.htaccess` files (or something similar), using `PHP built-in web server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, the built-in server provides no such things, it is only meant for development, and it's quite young still.

You can still fool the environment into functioning like that. e.g.: https://gist.github.com/3057918

Comment: Thank you! Then I'll better just use habitual Apache. :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits If you have an Apache server already installed on your computer (e.g. XAMPP). You could navigate to Project Properties for your web project in your Netbeans IDE and under Sources check the "copy files from Source folder to another location". The another location should be the folder in your Apache directory (e.g. XAMPP/htdocs/WEBFOLDER etc.). Then under "Run Configuration" point the Project URL to that folder. It works like magic. You work from your Netbeans IDE and it updates in two places at once. Solves the problem of .htacess and other php requirements (e.g. mcrypt etc.)